# Xamarin Android Spinner (MvxSpinner) bind with language resources and selecteditem

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.android, spinner, mvvmcross

I have a problem with Spinner (MvxSpinner) now for Android (but later I will need it for iOS too). I have in spinner period filter like This week, Last week, This month, etc.. This filter I need for my api services for get data... My problem is I want probably use Enum of Period types (or mb some better solution?) something like this:

**Enum PeriodTypes:**

```
public enum PeriodTypes
    {
        Unknown = -1,
        LastSevenDays = 0,
        LastWeek = 1,
        ThisWeek = 2
    }
```

I can make List of enum these PeriodTypes but my problem is I need to have in Spinner strings with language resources but in SelectedPeriod I need to know for example its PeriodTypes.LastWeek and use it for get data from api services and not like now just string in language resources...

My question is if I can use some object where I will have for example string text with language resoruce and this I will show in Spinner and in this object I need have Id of Enum or Enum type and in SelectedPeriod I will know what is selected.... Some tips how to make it?

**My ViewModel implementation right now is:**

```
public void Init(Shop shop)
        {
            _shop = shop;
            _shopName = shop.Name;
            InitializePeriodList();
            InitializeDailySales();
        }

        private void InitializePeriodList()
        {
            _periodList = new List<string>();

            _periodList.Add(CoreResources.Instance.LocalizedString(Constants.Periods, "LastSevenDays"));
            _periodList.Add(CoreResources.Instance.LocalizedString(Constants.Periods, "ThisWeek"));
            _periodList.Add(CoreResources.Instance.LocalizedString(Constants.Periods, "LastWeek"));

            string first = null;
            foreach (var s in _periodList)
            {
                first = s;
                break;
            }
            _selectedPeriod = first != null ? _periodList.FirstOrDefault() : CoreResources.Instance.LocalizedString(Constants.InfoMessages, "Error");
        }


   private List<string> _periodList;
        public List<string> PeriodList
        {
            get { return _periodList; }
            set
            {
                _periodList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => PeriodList);
            }
        }

        private string _selectedPeriod;
        public string SelectedPeriod
        {
            get { return _selectedPeriod; }
            set
            {
                _selectedPeriod = value;
        InitializeDailySales();
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedPeriod);
            }
        }
```

**Layout implementation:**

```
 <MvxSpinner

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/periodSpinner"

        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource PeriodList; SelectedItem SelectedPeriod"

        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I have an idea.. I can create method which will return List of Periods where Period will be object with LocalizedString and PeriodType. In ViewModel I will have this TempList and for Spinner I will create just string List with LocalizedString from TempList and when I will pick some in Spinner I will just find item = TempList.Where(q => q.LocalizedString.Equals(_selectedPeriod)) and I will have item.PeriodType....